# If $f \in L^1(X, M, \mu)$ there is a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu'$ such that $\int_E f d\mu = \int_E f d\mu'$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that given $f \in L^1(X, M, \mu)$ there is a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu'$ such that $\int_E f d\mu = \int_E f d\mu'$ for every measurable set $E$.

I tried proving this by absurd, stating that there is no such $\mu'$, but I couln't get anywhere.

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{x:|f(x)| >\frac 1 n\}$ has finite measure for each $n$ because  $\mu(\{x:|f(x)| >\frac 1 n\}) \leq n \int |f|d\mu< \infty$. Call this set $C_n$. Let $C =\cup_n C_n$ and $\mu'(A)=\mu (A\cap C)$. Then $\mu'$ is sigma finite and $\int_E fd\mu =\int_E f d\mu'$ for any measurable set $E$.

Comment: I will be happy to give more details if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! You used Chebyshev's inequality to prove that $C_n$ has finite measure, right?

Comment: Exactly. The inequality I have written is Chebyshev's inequality.